# How to identify QStandardItem's in a QListView without using the text field?

Tags: list, qt, oop, qt5, identifier

I'm trying to identify objects in my QListView item model. I'm currently using the text field of the list view which is obviously not the best idea.

This is my minimal code to fill the widget, see how I save a timestamp to the text field:

```
QListView * view = new QListView(this);
QStandardItemModel * model = new QStandardItemModel(this);
MyElements * mylist = getElements();
while (!mylist->isFirst()) 
{
    QStandardItem * item = new QStandardItem(mylist->getIcon(), mylist->getTimeString());
    model->appendRow(item);
    mylist = mylist->getPrevious();
}
view->setModel(model);
```

As you can see I have a unique timestamp for each `item` storing the unix time in milliseconds as a string. I can use this to identify my objects and this way I can always be sure which item is clicked.

Now, I wish to override the text with a more userfriendly string, like "*Click this to do stuff*" and not displaying the timestamp anymore.

But I still need the timestamp to identify each unique item in the list. Any idea where else I could store this data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the QStandardItem::setData() function to set any kind of data to the item. For example:

```
QStandardItem * item = new QStandardItem(list->getIcon(), "some text");
item->setData(list->getTimeString());
// ...
```

In order to get this data you will need to:

```
QString d = item->data().toString();
```

You can use custom roles to store multiple data sets in an item using Qt::UserRole.